# Microsoft bot builder framework AWS API gateway

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework

Could you please let me know if we can use Lambda function inside AWS gateway and Microsoft Bot Framework REST API principles for the bot framework with "Single tenant" type

When we use multi tenant, the API works like a charm. The moment it is changed to single tenant type in the app, we get error when replying to the conversation:

*{
"message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}*

Note: I we are able to generate the access token, but when post the response on service URL throws an error :https://smba.trafficmanager.net/v3/conversations//activities/

Comment: Can you compare the working and non-working access token at https://jwt.ms and see what is missing?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: apparently, the single tenant type doesn't work as per the documentation. For now we are using multi tenant setup